# How to calculate the horizontal (or vertical) projection in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I'm extracting frames (5 frames) from a video (car1.mp4). After that displaying the num of rows (and columns).
And then calculating the sum of pixel values of rows and columns of each frame. Finally plotting the graph between the number of columns (or rows) vs magnitude. Below is my code:

```
clear all
close all
clc

video=VideoReader('car1.mp4');
numFrames = video.NumberOfFrames;

for i = 1:1:5
    frames = read(video,i);
    imwrite(frames,['image' int2str(i), '.jpg'])
    frames = imresize(frames,[100 150]);

    sz = size(frames);
    numRows = sz(1);
    disp(numRows)
    numCols = sz(2);
    disp(numCols)

    rm = numRows*255;
    for j = 1:numRows
        sumr(j)=0;
        for k = 1:numCols
            pixels1 = impixel(frames,k,j);
            sumr(j)=sumr(j)+pixels1(1);
        end
    end
    s1 = rm./sumr;
    plot(s1)
    xlabel({'Horizontal Projection','(no. of columns)'})
    ylabel('Magnitude')

    rc = numCols*255;
    for u = 1:numCols
        sumc(u)=0;
        for v = 1:numRows
            pixels2 = impixel(frames,v,u);
            sumc(u)=sumc(u)+pixels2(1);
        end
    end
    s2 = rc./sumc;
    plot(s2)
    xlabel({'Vertical Projection','(no. of rows)'})
    ylabel('Magnitude')

 end
```

The main problem is, there are five frames extracting from the video but it shows output (plot between projection vs magnitude) of only one frame. I'm using for loop so that it shows each and every frame's output (plot between projection vs magnitude), but not showing. And the other problem is why it shows only one projection either Horizontal projection or Vertical projection?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: The reason you're only getting the plot for one frame is that, for each frame you're first overwriting `sumr` and then overwriting the existing figure to plot it. Then you overwrite`sumc` for each frame and overwrite the plot of `sumr` on the same figure. Repeat for all frames, and you only get one final plot. What results did you actually *want*? Do you want each plot in a separate figure, or in a subplot, or something else?

Comment: @beaker Yes, I want each plot in a separate figure. Can you help me?

Comment: Then add a line that says `figure` before each call to `plot`. You might want to research how to name the figure so you can tell them apart, though. See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html

Comment: @beaker my major mistake. solved it.